Laravel Vue axios endpoint fetches data and diplays in console log BUT not in Vue template
I have a laravel 8 project which is recently upgraded from version 7. I have updated webpack and package.json etc..
Here is a barebone structure of my Vue template which is supposed to display documents datatable(For now I am just dumping data). The data fetched from axios endpoint is correctly displayed in console log but is not available in template. I have tried debugging everyway, data initialized from axios is not even available in mounted() function also.
Below is my code
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="dummy-data">
      <h3>Dummy Data</h3>
      <pre>{{ mediaData }}</pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      mediaData: ''  // Initialize as a string
    };
  },
  methods: {
    fetchMediaData() {
      return axios.get(route('api.media.all-vue')) // Return the axios call
          .then((response) => {
            if (response.data && response.data.data) {
              // this.mediaData = response.data.data.map(item => item.filename).join(', '); // Assuming you want to join the filenames
              this.mediaData = "test assignment here";
              console.log('Fetched Media Data:', this.mediaData);
            } else {
              console.error('Unexpected API response format:', response.data);
            }
            return this.mediaData; // Return the data
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Failed to fetch media data:', error);
            throw error; // Throw the error for the caller to handle
          });
    }
  },
  async mounted() {

    try {
      this.mediaData = await this.fetchMediaData(); // Call fetchMediaData and await the result
      console.log('Mounted data is ' . this.mediaData);
    } catch (error) {
    }
  },
  updated() {
    console.log('Media Data updated:', this.mediaData);
  }
};
</script>



I have checked dummy data to be initialized in mounted() function this displays data in template but data initialized via axios end point is not available in mounted() function. This was working fine before the laravel upgrade to 8. Is there something I am missing here.
Please advise.

Hi, Can you create a reproducible example for this, as it does not seem to be any issue in the code.

I do not understand what you meant by reproducible example. Its from my laravel project data initialized is not available in mount() method for some reason.

@suryakumar See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . This is a requirement for code-related questions. Currently only you can reproduce the problem. "not available in mounted() function" - it's unclear what's the meaning of this. Is it the same as "is not available in template" but in other words, or something else?  "correctly displayed" - this needs to be verified. A possible reason for this would be that data is not what's expected by the component.

Also this {{ fetchedMediaData }} serves no good purpose and relies on a way vue deals with JSON output, which is not documented and shouldn't be relied on. If there's real template code to deal with data, please, provide it

@EstusFlask I have posted a more simplified version. I am receiving the data from axios endpoint. But to simplify I have assigned a variable with some data and it is available for console output in mount() function but not displaying in template.

It looks ok, especially since you added "return" to fetchMediaData, this is something that existing answer tried to address. Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem. Currently it's not reproducible. The two possibilities for data to be visible in console but not the template is that mediaData is not reactive (but it is because it exists in data()), and the component failed to instantiate (but then you'd see an error in the console)

@EstusFlask Please consider my other details that the code was working fine in laravel 7. after I upgraded to laravel 8 and made changes to webpack this problem is occurring. all my Vue pages are not showing data fetched using axios. other views are working fine. Only Vue files are having this problem.
I will try to create a reproduceable  code but its a big setup.

If you made changes to webpack and not just laravel part that's responsible for api this
then this would be a major concern. Anything could happen that would break vue reactivity. A common cause of this is that there are multiple vue copies per app. At this point fetch doesn't look relevant, as long as the response is successful (it is), you should be able to reproduce this with any asynchronous data change (setTimeout). The repro could be "hello world" with your webpack setup, the question doesn't say anything on this

@EstusFlask The question is very clearly laid In the laravel setup what might be the reason(s) for data initialized and available in the axios mounted function not to show up in Vue template. It would help me if anyone can give me directions on what to look for.

There's no de facto "laravel setup" regarding the way vue is used in laravel app. There's laravel mix, etc. it's very specific to your project. This is why a repro matters. What you describe means something could went wrong in webpack config or project deps or else. As I said, multiple vue copies can do this, you can try to find them with "npm dedupe". This are common reasons for reactive data to not being shown in a template when there are no reasonable explanations. fetch itself shouldn't matter because it reaches the "success" part. Nothing more specific can't be suggested without seeing it
